# Right way to reindex a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset which I filtered by location. The end result is something like this:

```
   column 1  column 2
 0        a         1
 106      b         2
 178      c         3
```

I guessed that the index values are skipping all over the place since the all the columns with the same locations aren't consecutive. To reset the indices, I did `df.reindex(index = np.arange(len(df)))`, and it worked... but broke everything else. The output is this:

```
   column 1  column 2
 0        a         1
 1      NAN       NAN
 12     NAN       NAN
```

I don't have any idea why this is happening, and how I can fix this. Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: `df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reset_index`:

```
>>> df.reset_index(drop=True)
  column 1  column 2
0        a         1
1        b         2
2        c         3
```